# Approximate integral in one line of code

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, functional-programming, comparative-review

This is what I came up with:

**Version 1:**

```
static double Integrate(Func<double, double> f, double low, double high, double delta)
{
    return Enumerable.Sum(Enumerable.Select(Enumerable.Range((int)(low / delta), (int)((high / delta) - (low / delta))), c => f(c * delta) * delta));
}
```

If I'm allowed to use a helper-method it becomes slightly shorter:

**Version 2:**

```
static double Integrate(Func<double, double> f, double low, double high, double delta)
{
    return Enumerable.Sum(Enumerable.Select(DoubleRange(low, high, delta), c => f(c) * delta));
}

public static IEnumerable<double> DoubleRange(double min, double max, double step)
{
    for (double value = min; value <= max; value += step)
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

Are there any better ways to do this? It's unfortunate LINQ doesn't have an overload for Enumerable.Range that takes floating point values. Are there ways of doing this with either more efficient or less characters of code?

Answer (score 4):

**Version 1.**
It gives incorrect results for some `delta` values.
Example: `Integrate(x => x * x, 0, 1, 0.1)` gives `0.285` whenever other methods give `0.385`.

**Version 2.**
Since the `delta` is a scalar that is a constant value for the `Enumerable.Sum`, it could be moved outside of the `Enumerable.Sum`.
Then we can replace the `c => f(c) * delta` with a method group `f`.
And also we can use `Enumerable`'s extension methods as extension methods:

```
static double Integrate(Func<double, double> f, double low, double high, double delta)
{
    return delta * DoubleRange(low, high, delta).Sum(f);
}

public static IEnumerable<double> DoubleRange(double min, double max, double step)
{
    for (double value = min; value <= max; value += step)
    {
        yield return value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
The `.Select(f).Sum()` was replaced with the `.Sum(f)` as [@mjolka](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/44723/mjolka) advised.

Comment: Nice answer! I think you can write `.Sum(f)` instead of `.Select(f).Sum()`.